# Perl: what's included in use 5.##.#?

Tags: perl

I've seen several [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050031/why-are-use-warnings-use-strict-not-default-in-perl) that state `use 5.12.0;` in Perl enables certain features/pragmas by default (e.g., `use strict;`).  Another example is in [UTF-8 and perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default) where it is stated that `use 5.14.0;` is

> optimal for Unicode string feature UTF-8 handling.

I seem to recall an available `use` declaration that provides certain defaults (e.g., `use strict; use warnings; use diagnostics;`), but can't remember the specifics.  How does one find out what is included in a given `use 5.##.#;` statement?  For example, what does `use 5.22.0;` provide by default? `use strict;`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is documented in [`perldoc feature`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html):

> It's possible to load multiple features together, using a feature bundle. The name of a feature bundle is prefixed with a colon, to distinguish it from an actual feature.
>
> ```
> use feature ":5.10";
> ```
>
> The following feature bundles are available:
>
> ```
> bundle    features included
> --------- -----------------
> :default  array_base
> :5.10     say state switch array_base
> :5.12     say state switch unicode_strings array_base
> :5.14     say state switch unicode_strings array_base
> :5.16     say state switch unicode_strings
>           unicode_eval evalbytes current_sub fc
> :5.18     say state switch unicode_strings
>           unicode_eval evalbytes current_sub fc
> :5.20     say state switch unicode_strings
>           unicode_eval evalbytes current_sub fc
> :5.22     say state switch unicode_strings
>           unicode_eval evalbytes current_sub fc
> ```

where

> ```
> use v5.10.0;
> ```
>
> will do an implicit
>
> ```
> no feature ':all';
> use feature ':5.10';
> ```
>
> and so on.

Automatic enabling of strictures is documented in [`perldoc -f use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html):

> if the specified Perl version is greater than or equal to 5.12.0, strictures are enabled lexically as with `use strict`.

Comment: Perfect.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Was I imagining it, or is there some `feature` subset that includes: strictures, warnings and diagnostics all in one go?  Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing in core that does that, but there could certainly be modules that do it. Perhaps you're thinking of [Modern::Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Modern::Perl), which enables `strict`, `warnings`, and all 5.10 features, among other things.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's it! Modern::Perl. Thanks again

Comment: there's also [common::sense](http://p3rl.org/common::sense) and [Defaults::Modern](http://p3rl.org/Defaults::Modern) and probably others I can't remember

Answer (score 2):

`use 5.12.0;` does `use feature ':5.12';`, so you get

- say
- state
- switch
- unicode_strings
- array_base

The feature bundles are documented in [feature.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?feature#FEATURE_BUNDLES)'s documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the link to features.pm's documentation. Great resource to keep bookmarked

Answer (score 2):

For enhancements not covered by [feature](http://p3rl.org/feature), you can use [Syntax::Construct](http://p3rl.org/Syntax::Construct).

Comment: Very interesting module!